# Where to find info on the Minimum Requirements for running Cesium?

Tags: 3d, cesiumjs

I need Cesium for a project that I'm working on, but I need to know what the CPU, GPU, AND RAM space it requires. I can't seem to find anything online. Does anyone know/know where I can find that info?

Comment: Make sure to use a 64-bit web browser vs 32-bit browser to access > 2GB RAM if want to access large amounts of data. A discussion of system requirements is in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/zR5AWwdQaGI).

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from a similar question asked in the [Cesium-Dev Google User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cesium-dev):

> The only real requirement is that your browser has WebGL support.  If
>   you see a spinning cube on this website, your browser supports WebGL:
>   https://get.webgl.org/ Cesium will run faster on a computer with more
>   processing power and a good video card, but it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Personal experience shows that integrated graphics on notebooks have low fps(~10-20 frames per second) even on the map without any data. It is probably good idea to have dedicated graphics card.

Here is discussion thread in Cesium community.

https://community.cesium.com/t/cesium-cpu-gpu-and-ram-recommendations/3594